# Android Maps API Key

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I wonder why I receive the following error message:

```
05-30 19:39:20.141 8833-9063/nl.itc.geofara.app E/Google Maps Android API:
In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)                                                                           
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:                                                                           
API Key: "***********************************QWPo"                                                                              
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>):
63:BB:2F:AF:0C:03:E7:C0:02:CD:5E:EF:EB:D0:F6:EB:F4:F2:CC:1C;nl.itc.geofara.app
```

My developer console shows the following:
[image: console.developers.google.com]
The API is enabled:
[image: console.developers.google.com]
My gradle config looks like this:
    ...

```
signingConfigs {

    release {
        storeFile file("${geoFaraKeystoreReleaseLocation}")
        keyAlias "${geoFaraReleaseKeyAlias}"
        storePassword "${geoFaraReleaseStorePassword}"
        keyPassword "${geoFaraReleaseKeyPassword}"
    }

    debug {
        storeFile file("${geoFaraKeystoreDebugLocation}")
        keyAlias "${geoFaraDebugKeyAlias}"
        storePassword "${geoFaraDebugStorePassword}"
        keyPassword "${geoFaraDebugKeyPassword}"
    }
}

buildTypes {

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release            
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [ GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY:"\"${googleMapsKey}\""]
    }

    debug {
        versionNameSuffix " Debug"
        debuggable true
        manifestPlaceholders = [ GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY:"\"${googleMapsKey}\""]
    }
}
```

The corresponding gradle.properties part is shown here:

```
# Google API keys
googleMapsKey=***********************************QWPo

# Debug keystore
geoFaraKeystoreDebugLocation = keystore/debug.keystore
geoFaraDebugKeyAlias = geofara
geoFaraDebugStorePassword = *********
geoFaraDebugKeyPassword = ********

# Release keystore.
geoFaraKeystoreReleaseLocation = keystore/release.keystore
geoFaraReleaseKeyAlias = geofara
geoFaraReleaseStorePassword = ******
geoFaraReleaseKeyPassword = **********
```

And then there's the AndroidManifest.xml (I am aware these are more permissions than required for maps to work):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="nl.itc.geofara.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Tell the system this app requires OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- rear facing cam -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- users location -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- accelerometer -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- compass -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".GeoFaraApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.editor.EditorActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.editor.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <service android:name=".data.SyncService" />
        <service android:name=".data.PersistenceService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".data.SyncService$SyncOnConnectionAvailable"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thought I followed all steps or have I missed something?

Comment: Not sure if helps but my Manifest states `android:value="@string/google_maps_key"` on **meta-data** before **activity** tag. Then my **strings.xml** has `<string name="google_maps_key">mykey</string>` (with "mykey" being my key - you would have it changed to yours).

Comment: As far as I can tell, my setup is fine in this regard. If I were to change the line android:value="${GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY} so that it wasn't fine, I wouldn't be getting API Key: "***********************************QWPo" in the error message, right?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I placed manifestPlaceholders inside defaultConfig instead